# Living in France while remote working for a UK company

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom, france

I'm planning to move to France but I will still be employed by a UK company.
According to the HMRC website, my taxes will be payable in the UK but I read on an old forum that the French authorities may not be happy about it.

Anyone with a similar experience that can help?

Comment: probably best off asking [expatriates.se]

Comment: @AakashM Thanks! I didn't know we had that.